# Count number of subsets whose sum is greater than or equal to k

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given an array with n elements , one need to count number of subsets whose sum is greater than or equal to k.

Eg arr[] = {1,5,9,2,3}, k =16

1+5+9+2=17

1+5+9+3=18

1+5+9+2+3=20

5+9+2=16

5+9+3=17

5+9+2+3=19

Answer is 6.

One approach what i know is to use dynamic programming using bit masking and check if sum>=k and increment the count.
Problem with this approach is N should be very small since bit masking involves exponential running time.

Is there any other efficient algorithm for the above problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The elements are all positive?

Comment: It can be combination of both. But for simplicity we will consider only positive elements

Comment: @Henry Let us consider only positive elements

Answer (score 1):

Make array `Counts[Sum+1]` where Sum is sum of all elements
Set `Counts[0] = 1`, other elements - zero
For ever `x=arr[i]` scan Counts array from the end and increment those entries, that could be composed from existing so far sums and `x`

```
if Counts[j - arr[i]] > 0 then  //this check might be omitted
   Counts[j] = Counts[j - arr[i]] +  Counts[j]
```

Then sum non-zero Counts entries for `j>=k`

Complexity is `O(Sum * N)`

If range of possible sums is large but number of possible sums is not so high (like `arr=[1, 2, 3, 100000000, 100000001]` array), you can exploit memoization approach and store only really existing variants in the map

Example:

```
arr=[1,2,3,5]
Counts = [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
after arr[0]=1
Counts = [1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
after arr[1]=2
Counts = [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
after arr[2]=3
Counts = [1,1,1,2,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0]
after arr[3]=5
Counts = [1,1,1,2,1,2,2,1,2,1,1,1]

Counts[8] could be composed from 5 and existing Counts[3] with two variants
1+2+5; 3+5
```

Comment: This approach works too, if k and element value is small. What if each element in arr is very big say 10^9. So sum of all elements will be n*10^9. If we iterate through the entire sum range, program will run for ever.

Comment: @Chandan You did not give range information in the question. I added note about memoization.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to use recursion to create the subsets and stop the recursion when the sum of the elements omitted from the original set is greater than total-k, where total is the sum of all elements of the array.

Here's some Java code that illustrates the approach:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.BitSet;
import java.util.List;

public class SubSet
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Integer[] set = { 1, 5, 9, 2, 3 };
        List<List<Integer>> subsets = subsetsK(set, 16);
        for (List<Integer> subset : subsets)
        {
            System.out.println(subset);
        }
    }

    static List<List<Integer>> subsetsK(Integer[] arr, int k)
    {
        int t = 0;
        for (int n : arr) t += n;

        List<List<Integer>> subsets = new ArrayList<>();
        allSubsets(subsets, arr, new BitSet(arr.length), 0, 0, t - k);
        return subsets;
    }

    public static void allSubsets(List<List<Integer>> subsets, Integer[] arr, BitSet off, int pos, int sum, int lim)
    {
        if(sum > lim) return;

        if(pos == arr.length)
        {
            subsets.add(toSubset(arr, off));
            return;
        }

        off.set(pos);
        allSubsets(subsets, arr, off, pos + 1, sum + arr[pos], lim);

        off.clear(pos);
        allSubsets(subsets, arr, off, pos + 1, sum, lim);
    }

    static List<Integer> toSubset(Integer[] arr, BitSet off)
    {
        List<Integer> ss = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            if (!off.get(i))
                ss.add(arr[i]);
        }
        return ss;
    }   
}
```

Output:

```
[5, 9, 3]
[5, 9, 2]
[5, 9, 2, 3]
[1, 5, 9, 3]
[1, 5, 9, 2]
[1, 5, 9, 2, 3]
```

You can run/edit the code here: [Ideone](http://ideone.com/B8xDhd)